# Where can I place eligible candidates for CDI in a Glassfish v3 deployment?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, jboss-weld

I have code in one jar (a.jar) which contains an `@Inject X x`.

I want to satisfy the injection with an implementation in *another* jar (b.jar, being a valid bean archive etc.).

To my understanding, I cannot deploy a.jar and b.jar in separate WAR standalone archives as these are independent CDI-wise.    I may be able to put b.jar in the lib folder that Glassfish provides to all deployments (but is this "pure Java 6 EE" and this mean I cannot deploy in the same way as a war or an ear?).  I may be able to provide b.jar in an EAR placed in lib along with a.war or a.jar but I am unfamiliar with this.

My question is **which options do I have for deploying a.jar and b.jar** so that Glassfish (currently 3.0.1 but I will consider 3.1.1 if it works better) will correctly resolve this dependency?   I am looking for an exhaustive list.

(EDIT:  I'd prefer a solution where b.jar can be deployed independently of a.jar)

Answer (score 1):

I think a good option is putting `a.jar` and`b.jar` in the `lib` folder of your project. Please tell if you think it has drawbacks.

Comment: I'd like to separate the two jars into separate deployments if at all possible

Answer (score 1):

I would see if I could turn the relevant objects in `b.jar` into EJBs, effectively turning `b.jar` into a EJB 3 'service'.

Then, in `a.jar` (and any other code that needs the service), I would use a CDI Producer method to perform JNDI lookup, allowing me to `@Inject` the EJB just like any local resource.

Alternatively, if you can also turn `a.jar` into an EJB 3 'service' then EJB's from `b.jar` can be injected directly by the container (using Java EE `@EJB` or `@Resource` injection) into `a.jar`'s EJBs.